# Need help making and waiting for a reocurring event

Tags: c#

I am having multiple problems, there are going to be multiple usernames and passwords in the listbox... 
I need the application to wait while and account is in the text boxes, and then when the textboxes are clear then the account next in the listbox can go to the next line..

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lbAccounts.Items.Clear();
        OpenFileDialog Open = new OpenFileDialog();
        Open.Title = "Select Email List";
        Open.Filter = "Text Document|*.txt|All Files|*.*";
        try
        {
            Open.ShowDialog();
            StreamReader Import = new StreamReader(Convert.ToString(Open.FileName));
            while (Import.Peek() >= 0)
                lbAccounts.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(Import.ReadLine()));

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    private void SendTestMail()
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(txtUser.Text, txtPass.Text);
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUser.Text);
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("example@gmail.com"));
            msg.Subject = "Hi, I'm Valid :D";
            msg.Body = txtUser.Text + ":" + txtPass.Text;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = loginInfo;
            client.Send(msg);

            lbGoodAccounts.Items.Add(txtUser.Text + ":" + txtPass.Text);
            txtUser.Clear();
            txtPass.Clear();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            lbFailAccounts.Items.Add(txtUser.Text + ":" + txtPass.Text);
            txtUser.Clear();
            txtPass.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendTestMail();
    }

    private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter Write;
        SaveFileDialog Open = new SaveFileDialog();
        try
        {
            Open.Filter = ("Text Document|*.txt|All Files|*.*");
            Open.FileName = ("Good Gmail Accounts");
            Open.ShowDialog();
            Write = new StreamWriter(Open.FileName);
            for (int I = 0; I < lbGoodAccounts.Items.Count; I++)
            {
                Write.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(lbGoodAccounts.Items[I]));
            }
            Write.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex.Message));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: And your _specific_ question related to a _specific_ programming related issue is what exactly?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to parse the string user:password from the listbox and send to the two textboxes in which the user is typing? Is the user working with the listbox or textboxes?

Comment: @Matthias The user will be no one, I am the only one that will use this. It is because I want to test some accounts in large amounts and i import them to the listbox, and from the list box they go to the testboxes and from the textboxes they will be comfirmed real accounts or not. Real accounts go to one listbox and nonreal accounts go to other listbox.

Comment: You should post different questions for each single topic then. Anyway, the code from Aleksander below is correct. It takes the currently selected line of the first listbox and sends it to the two text boxes.

Comment: Ok, but if I put that under a button and there is multiple lines of accounts in the listbox then how will that go out? Will the account under the one that just go picked wait for a response? or atleast wait until the textboxes are clear?

Comment: @user1951147 The code I posted will work on a button click too.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you right this is the code you will need :

```
 void AccountsListBox_Click (object sender, EventArgs args) 
 {
    if (AccountsListBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
        return;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxName.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxPass.Text)) 
        return; // stop processing if they have some data

    // otherwise get acccount:password, 
    // split it into acc and pass and write them to TextBoxes
    string value = AccountsListBox.Items[AccountsListBox.SelectedIndex];
    string[] values = value.Split(':');
    if (values.Length != 2)
        return;  // wrong format        

    var acc   = values[0];
    var pass  = values[1];

    TextBoxName.Text = acc;
    TextBoxPass.Text = pass;
}
```

I haven't used WinForms for some time so if you find some errors please correct them :)

See [MSDN ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) documentation for details.

Comment: i would cache the split result.

Comment: I am getting errors on AccountsListBox.ItemIndex, and the value.Split

Comment: AccountsListBox is just a placeholder for the name of your list box with accounts.

Comment: I know, I replaced it with mine which was lbAccounts and it still showing error : 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'ItemIndex' and no extension method 'ItemIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Checkout the [MSDN for ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx). It is SelectedIndex. I will change the code above.

Comment: Now I am getting this error on the .Items part : Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Hey common, we can not do all your homework. Just put an explicit cast there. I will change the code again. By the way, you could also use RegEx instead of splitting directly. Anyway, one problem remains. If a  : character occurs within the username or password, the code above won't work.

Comment: Sorry about asking for so much, i have never learned about c# in a class before i am still in highschool and barely started to use computers